# Unity Mobile Game in a Xamarin Project

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, xamarin

I have a game built in Unity,

How do I add it into a Xamarin Project?

I have exported the game of Android Devices but I don't seem to be able to put the two things together

Thanks

I tried to add the exported game into the project in dependencies but didn't work

Comment: You create a binding library around the aar you export, then you can start it inside of your Xamarin App.